# Import from api into multiple excel cells

Tags: vba, excel

I have an api which displays a two-dimension array.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 4
            [2] => 5
        )

)
```

How can I import the api into excel so that the first number(0) will go to A1. The second number(1) to B1. Something like this

```
   A  B  C
1| 0  1  2
2| 3  4  5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the array in Excel already it is fairly trivial, just need to make sure your range is the same size as your array, you can do this using the lower boundary and upper boundary of the array like this:

```
Sub MultiDimension()
Dim MyArr(2, 3) As Long
MyArr(0, 0) = 0
MyArr(0, 1) = 1
MyArr(0, 2) = 2
MyArr(1, 0) = 3
MyArr(1, 1) = 4
MyArr(1, 2) = 5
Range("A1:A1").Resize(UBound(MyArr, LBound(MyArr) + 1), UBound(MyArr, UBound(MyArr))) = MyArr
End Sub
```

Edit: This will do what you want.

```
Sub ReadFromAPI()
Dim MyString As String, MyVal As String, D1 As Long, D2 As Long, MyArr() As Variant, X As Long, APIURL As String

APIURL = "http://iqamah.org/api/test.php"
With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    .Open "GET", APIURL, False
    .Send
    MyString = .ResponseText
End With
If MyString <> "" Then
    D1 = ((Len(MyString) - Len(Replace(MyString, " => Array", ""))) / 9) - 1
    D2 = (Len(MyString) - Len(Replace(MyString, "(", ""))) - 1
    ReDim MyArr(D1, D2)
    For X = LBound(Split(MyString, vbLf)) To UBound(Split(MyString, vbLf))
        MyVal = Split(MyString, vbLf)(X)
        If Replace(MyVal, "=>", "") <> MyVal Then
            If Replace(MyVal, "=> Array", "") <> MyVal Then
                D1 = Mid(MyVal, InStr(1, MyVal, "[") + 1, (InStr(1, MyVal, "]")) - (InStr(1, MyVal, "[") + 1))
            Else
                D2 = Mid(MyVal, InStr(1, MyVal, "[") + 1, InStr(1, MyVal, "]") - (InStr(1, MyVal, "[") + 1))
                MyArr(D1, D2) = Right(MyVal, Len(MyVal) - (InStr(1, MyVal, "=> ")) - 2)
            End If
        End If
    Next
    Range("A1:A1").Resize(D1 + 1, D2 + 1) = MyArr
Else
    MsgBox "Nothing returned, Site might be down", vbOKOnly
End If
End Sub
```

Code as a worksheet event:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim MyString As String, MyVal As String, D1 As Long, D2 As Long, MyArr() As Variant, X As Long, APIURL As String

If Target = Range("M19") Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    APIURL = "http://iqamah.org/api/test.php?id=" & Target.Text
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", APIURL, False
        .Send
        MyString = .ResponseText
    End With
    If MyString <> "" Then
        D1 = ((Len(MyString) - Len(Replace(MyString, " => Array", ""))) / 9) - 1
        D2 = (Len(MyString) - Len(Replace(MyString, "(", ""))) - 1
        ReDim MyArr(D1, D2)
        For X = LBound(Split(MyString, vbLf)) To UBound(Split(MyString, vbLf))
            MyVal = Split(MyString, vbLf)(X)
            If Replace(MyVal, "=>", "") <> MyVal Then
                If Replace(MyVal, "=> Array", "") <> MyVal Then
                    D1 = Mid(MyVal, InStr(1, MyVal, "[") + 1, (InStr(1, MyVal, "]")) - (InStr(1, MyVal, "[") + 1))
                Else
                    D2 = Mid(MyVal, InStr(1, MyVal, "[") + 1, InStr(1, MyVal, "]") - (InStr(1, MyVal, "[") + 1))
                    MyArr(D1, D2) = Right(MyVal, Len(MyVal) - (InStr(1, MyVal, "=> ")) - 2)
                End If
            End If
        Next
        Range("A1:A1").Resize(D1 + 1, D2 + 1) = MyArr
    Else
        MsgBox "Nothing returned, Site might be down", vbOKOnly
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I updated the website a little bit.. I am getting this wired error
Run-time error '9':
Subscript out of range

Comment: This is the line it highlights ReDim MyArr(D1, D2)

Comment: What URL are you using? I need to see the data it is trying to break down.

Comment: That is massively different to the samples, will there always only be one element per element?

Comment: yes, sorry mate. I dont know what I was thinking last night. I woke up and I was like woah I changed the whole format. lol but yes only be one element per element?

Comment: You will need to json encode your data server side first.

Comment: When you say you changed the whole format, are you talking about the site? I was under the impression that you didn't have any control over it. If you do then as Anis suggested, output a more useful format. The solution I built for you was splitting a text string and searching for keywords (keychars really) and whilst it works, you can see that it is not scalable or easily maintainable.

Comment: what kind of format will be better comma after each one?
Feb 01,14:49,16:07,21:11,23:54,02:16,02:16,03:34

Comment: As Anis said go with JSON or even XML, Excel imports XML directly and it would be fairly easy to wrap a refresh and tailored link based around M19

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend exporting the PHP array to a CSV file, should come out like you expect.

Answer (score 0):

The range you are specifying for target-value must contains some number to avoid error...

You should try the following changes, working for me...

In the Procedure `Worksheet_Change()` change this line of code:

```
D1 = ((Len(MyString) - Len(Replace(MyString, " => Array", ""))) / 9) - 1
```

with plus (+) as:

```
D1 = ((Len(MyString) - Len(Replace(MyString, " => Array", ""))) / 9) + 1
```

And this

```
D2 = (Len(MyString) - Len(Replace(MyString, "(", ""))) - 1
```

with this one:

```
D2 = (Len(MyString) - Len(Replace(MyString, "(", ""))) + 1
```

Then use the following procedure to run the code:

```
Sub runCode()
    Worksheet_Change (Worksheets("sheet1").Range("m19"))
End Sub
```